# Why does my nerd tree have these odd characters

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Trying to get a nice vim setup going. I'd like to have nerd tree working at it's best, but when i use it it's got these chars in front of each section:

```
?~V?
```

Looks like this:

```
?~V? project/$
  ?~V? tools/$
```

Comment: The fix for me was what was recommended here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753286/nerd-tree-enter-does-not-open-sub-dirs

Comment: I personally had to recompile vim. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753286/nerd-tree-enter-does-not-open-sub-dirs/14842164#14842164

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same problem and was able to fix it by uncommenting UTF-8 and leaving ISO-8879-1 commented out in /etc/locale.gen. Then I ran locale-gen and restarted. Also added 'export LANG=en_US.UTF-8' to my .bashrc. Here are the results of my locale settings once it started working:

```
[lysistrata@(none) ~]$ locale -a
C
en_US.utf8
POSIX
[lysistrata@(none) ~]$
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a terminal vim (you don't mention platform, flavour nor version...) I'd say you either

- need a UTF8 aware console (execute `stty` to find out if you have it enabled)
- or you need a different TERM setting. Executing
  `vim -T`
  will list the builtin ones.

Comment: Oops. I'm using Mac OS Lion's terminal. stty returns iutf8. and vim -T returns an error: E437: terminal capability "cm" required