# Nerd tree: enter does not open sub dirs

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I installed NERDTree via Pathogen on Mac OSX 10.6.8.

When I vim a dir, I cannot enter into sub dirs with enter key.  Furthermore, the dirs look like this:

```
?~V? doc/
```

What's going on?

Comment: It looks like Vim is unable to display the arrow or `+` sign. Vim in the terminal (I think) or MacVim? Vim version? If Vim in the terminal what does `$ echo $TERM` in the terminal says and do you use Terminal.app or iTerm?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Putting this in my .vimrc solved the problem: `let g:NERDTreeDirArrows=0`

The creator gave me the fix: https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/108

Comment: Thanks. Definitely use the reference link here as it helped solve my problem. I had to set encoding=utf-8 in the top of .vimrc file and everything worked

Answer (score 18):

On Mountain Lion 10.8.2

This worked for me

```
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Thanks. This had to be added to the .bashrc file which is in C:Users\<your user name> directory.

Comment: Worked for me on FreeBSD 10.3

Answer (score 12):

I followed jernkuan's answer but didn't work. What worked for me was typing `:set encoding=utf-8` inside vim   But I lose this when I exit out of vim. I have to do this everytime I am on vim

Comment: You can add `set encoding=utf-8` to your .vimrc to enable this by default! Any command that you enter in vim you can add to your .vimrc. Your solution was the only one that worked for me!

Comment: I like this solution the best since it isolates the changes to vim.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. combined with haff's comment

Answer (score 9):

If you'd still like to try to get the arrow characters to work, here is my answer from [Why does my nerd tree have these odd characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375198/why-does-my-nerd-tree-have-these-odd-characters). I run Arch Linux, so your mileage may vary.

I had this exact same problem and was able to fix it by uncommenting UTF-8 and leaving ISO-8879-1 commented out in /etc/locale.gen. Then I ran locale-gen and restarted. Also added 'export LANG=en_US.UTF-8' to my .bashrc. Here are the results of my locale settings once it started working:

```
[lysistrata@(none) ~]$ locale -a
C
en_US.utf8
POSIX
[lysistrata@(none) ~]$
```

Comment: The LANG environment variable is the key.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using RedHat 6.1 and vim 7.3 and had to recompile vim with multibyte support.

```
$ cd ~/src && wget ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/unix/vim-7.3.tar.bz2
$ tar xjf vim-7.3.tar.bz2 && cd vim-7.3
$ ./configure --enable-multibyte
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Then verify that multibyte support has been enabled.

```
$ vim --version | grep byte
-arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse +builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
+mouse_xterm +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg -osfiletype
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `locale` on your system, if output is something like this one
`LANG=C` then do the following steps:

1. `sudo echo "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.conf`
2. `sudo locale-gen` and `sudo reboot`

check your `locale` again. Hope this can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

On my fedora 27, I just put `set encoding=utf-8` into mine `~/.vimrc` file, and it starts working properly.